# Error transferring django project from windows to linux

Tags: linux, django, static, http-status-code-404

My project with py3 and django worked well in win10. But when I tried to make it work in linux, a 404 eror of static file appeared.

**The error message is below.**

[28/Sep/2017 09:32:57] "GET /static/home/cys/prj/.../cls_demo/static/c73f33679ff4328816dee4450044174e.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1955

** Settings.py **

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collected_static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "clsapp", "static"),
]
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder"
)

**Sample of how I call static files through my templates**

{% load staticfiles %}
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('{% static img_path %}')">
</div>
```

There is different code between win10 version and linux version. Why did this error appear? How to fix it...

Comment: There is no difference in how Linux and Windows deal with static files. You must have forgotten to carry over a setting.

Comment: Is this image actually present in your static file?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct capitalisation of your files/code. The problem could be that you have moved from a case-insensitive file system to a case-sensitive one.

Comment: Usually, there is no difference in how Linux and Windows deal with static files. I had made a mistake with img_path. The absolute path worked well in win10, but failed in linux. The img_path using relative path solved the problem. Thank you!